# Why is Google app so large?

Tags: google

I see that [Google](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox&hl=en) app takes 120 Mb of storage. Since it's just an app to search things on the web, why is it so darn large?

Are there any more functions (except searching the web) that it does to justify taking up so much space?

Comment: A bit of analysis tells me that majority of space is taken by offline language files in (`data` directory ~ 70MB and another ~30MB the classes.dex files take a bit of the remaining space)

Comment: Thanks @xavier_fakerat . You can still post this as an answer if you like.

Comment: Thanks was away, but seeing that a better, more detailed answer was posted, I guess there is no need, but thanks for the feedback :)

Comment: As of 2022, it's more than 600 MB already, and that's only the apk, not including user data and cache.

Comment: Yeah, for some reason the bloat in the apk increased more than threefold over as many years.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Google App does more than just searching the web, it customizes your feed, updates you about stories, weather, etc., offers Google Assistant, Learns about how you use it and much more.
This results into an App size of about 120MB(apk size varies according to specific screen densities or [Application Binary Interfaces](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis.html)) after installation without app data.
Analysing [APK Structure](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/reduce-apk-size.html#apk-structure) of Google App 7.20.16.21.arm, I got following details which takes about 115MB of storage and further 90MB of data is stored on phone, making the total app size of 205MB.
The app size of approximately 115MB is categorized as:
**classes.dex ~ 42MB(39%):**

> Contains the classes compiled in the DEX file format understood by the Dalvik/ART virtual machine.

**resources.arsc ~ 30MB(27%):**

> Contains compiled resources. This file contains the XML content from all configurations of the res/values/ folder. The packaging tool extracts this XML content, compiles it to binary form, and archives the content. This content includes language strings and styles, as well as paths to content that is not included directly in the resources.arsc file, such as layout files and images.

**lib/ ~ 23MB(20%):**

> Contains the compiled code that is specific to the software layer of a processor. This directory contains a subdirectory for each platform type, like armeabi, armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a, x86, x86_64, and mips.

**res/ ~ 10MB(8%):**

> Contains resources that aren't compiled into resources.arsc.

**assets/ ~ 5MB(4%):**

> Contains the app's assets, which the app can retrieve using an AssetManager object.

**META-INF/ ~ 2MB(1%):**

> Contains the CERT.SF and CERT.RSA signature files, as well as the MANIFEST.MF manifest file.

**Rest ~ 1MB(1%):**
org/, AndroidManifest.xml, build-data.properties, etc.

Further 90MB of data stored on disk consists of *search history*, *feed data* which grows with the app usage.

Comment: I have never used this app, why does it take the further 90MB of search history?

Comment: If you have never used Google app then I think data stored on your phone will be less than 25MB. That 90MB is in my case.

Comment: The user data for the Google app is 700+ MB in my case. I find clearing it just causes it to redownload the user data. It's not obvious how to reduce the size, but I know in my nexus 5 days the app was about 100mb with user and cache data.